# Changing URL without reloading in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

I got a function that changes the URL on button click.

Problem:

> AngularJS obviously reloads on URL change automatically.

```
var newUrl = ($state.current.url).replace('{navigationId}', $stateParams.navigationId).replace('{tabId}', tab.stateReference);
history.pushState('', tab.stateReference, newUrl);
```

How can we change the URL without reloading the page in AngularJS?

**Edit:**

I tried to use `reloadOnSearch: false` as described here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider - but it still reloads the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should have `$state` for each & every state you want to navigate. Then you can `$state.go` to the particular state

```
$state.go('toState');
```

If you want to pass parameters to that `$state`, then you should pass them on `$state.go`

```
$state.go('view', { 'index': 123, 'anotherKey': 'This is a test' });
```

Make sure that your `$state` is ready to accept those parameters on `params`

```
.state('full', {
            url: '/full',
            templateUrl: 'js/content/templates/FullReadView.html',
            params: { opmlFeed:null, source:null },
            controller: 'FullReadCtrl'
        })
```

More to read on [Wiki](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki)

Comment: Probably thats what Im doing wrong. Basically I use one state `.state('tables'...` and the view is changed by md-tabs (angular material). So I cannot use `$state.go()`. I cant really change all the system now anymore though, its quite big ..:/ - I found https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider "reloadOnSearch" and tried to set it to `false` but it doesnt do anything I think - probably cause I use .state instead of route?!